# Why use a single framework such as J2EE & .NET over using a variety of framworks in an N-Tier application?

Tags: .net, jakarta-ee, model-view-controller, architecture, n-tier-architecture

I have seen N-Tier stacks such as Python with React & AWS. I can't understand why you would want to use a single framework such as J2EE and .NET over a variety of them such as the Python stack mentioned.

My only guess is that having a single framework allows for better communication between the layers - I'm sure this is not a good enough reason since the Python stack communicates well with AWS & React too.

What do you think the reasons should be for adopting a single framework when choosing an N-Tier stack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most important reason is not technical, it's human.  Normalizing your tech stack allows you to both hire standardized staff, allow staff to work at all levels of the application stack, and have back-fill capabilities in case someone leaves the project.

Heterogeneous environments *can* work, they are more expensive as they tend to bifurcate teams along tiers, which reduces flexibility and increases management complexity.  Additionally, adding multiple technologies often increases deployment and infrastructure complexity.  Sometimes this is justifiable, J2EE's UI frameworks can be very limiting, and are more and more commonly being replaced by other UI frameworks like React or Angular.

Comment: It's easy to forget the human in a technical setup - fantastic response.Why do you think J2EE frameworks are limiting and being replaced however.

Comment: That is going to ignite way too much of a flame-war, but JSF is an atrocious front-end framework.  Using it feels like a punishment, to be inflicted upon those who can't be bothered to understand HTML and JavaScript, and desperately yearn to spend endless weeks writing XML files instead of HTML and JavaScript....  This is purely my opinion, and to be fair, I haven't used JSF in many years, but I certainly hated it when I did use it.